# SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools

Tags: ros2

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
```

I run `colcon build` and I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
```

I also downgraded setptools to 58.2.0 but I still get the error
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Problem is with your version of Setuptools . Downgrading it will remove this warning but that might cause problems with other as dependencies .
- Downgrade it to 58.2 version through pip
- Solved in a [Video](https://studio.youtube.com/video/uq-ZuxHetDo/edit)
- More Explanation provided here: [Question link](https://answers.ros.org/question/396439/setuptoolsdeprecationwarning-setuppy-install-is-deprecated-use-build-and-pip-and-other-standards-based-tools/#400052)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).