# setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I was trying to setup [this](https://github.com/stefan-ainetter/grasp_det_seg_cnn) repository locally. I run the `python setup.py install` command to setup the library. The contents of the setup.py file is as follows:

```
...
setuptools.setup(
    # Meta-data
    name="GraspDetSeg_CNN",
    author="Stefan Ainetter",
    author_email="stefan.ainetter@icg.tugraz.at",
    description="Grasp Detection and Segmentation for Pytorch, code based on Seamless Scene Segmentation (https://github.com/mapillary/seamseg).",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    ],

    # Versioning
    use_scm_version={"root": ".", "relative_to": __file__, "write_to": "grasp_det_seg/_version.py"},

    # Requirements
    setup_requires=["setuptools_scm"],
    python_requires=">=3, <4",

    # Package description
    packages=[
        "grasp_det_seg",
        "grasp_det_seg.algos",
        "grasp_det_seg.config",
        "grasp_det_seg.data_OCID",
        "grasp_det_seg.models",
        "grasp_det_seg.modules",
        "grasp_det_seg.modules.heads",
        "grasp_det_seg.utils",
        "grasp_det_seg.utils.bbx",
        "grasp_det_seg.utils.nms",
        "grasp_det_seg.utils.parallel",
        "grasp_det_seg.utils.roi_sampling",
    ],
    ext_modules=[
        make_extension("nms", "grasp_det_seg.utils"),
        make_extension("bbx", "grasp_det_seg.utils"),
        make_extension("roi_sampling", "grasp_det_seg.utils")
    ],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": BuildExtension},
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

I guess this tries to install another dependency named GraspDetSeg_CNN with the link https://github.com/mapillary/seamseg. After running the command `python setup.py install` I am getting the following error. The error is too long so I am cutting some portions that I think are not related.

```
home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
running install
/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/top_level.txt
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying grasp_det_seg/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/grasp_det_seg
/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:201: _Warning: Package 'grasp_det_seg.__pycache__' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        ############################
        # Package would be ignored #
        ############################
        Python recognizes 'grasp_det_seg.__pycache__' as an importable package[^1],
        but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

        This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
        package, please make sure that 'grasp_det_seg.__pycache__' is explicitly added
        to the `packages` configuration field.

        Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
        (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
        instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

        You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

        - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

        If you don't want 'grasp_det_seg.__pycache__' to be distributed and are
        already explicitly excluding 'grasp_det_seg.__pycache__' via
        `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
        you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
        combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

        You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

        - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


        [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
              even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
              On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
              directory, all directories are treated like packages.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
 
  check.warn(importable)
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/grasp_det_seg/_version.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/grasp_det_seg
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/grasp_det_seg/_version.py to _version.cpython-37.pyc
creating stub loader for grasp_det_seg/utils/nms/_backend.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
creating stub loader for grasp_det_seg/utils/bbx/_backend.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
creating stub loader for grasp_det_seg/utils/roi_sampling/_backend.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/grasp_det_seg/utils/nms/_backend.py to _backend.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/grasp_det_seg/utils/bbx/_backend.py to _backend.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/grasp_det_seg/utils/roi_sampling/_backend.py to _backend.cpython-37.pyc
copying GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying GraspDetSeg_CNN.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 77, in <module>
    include_package_data=True,
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 80, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 129, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 212, in run
    os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 265, in zip_safe
    return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 339, in analyze_egg
    safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
  File "/home/ozaland/anaconda3/envs/fedgrasp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 376, in scan_module
    code = marshal.load(f)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

All the packages that are in the packages list in the `setup.py` file are ignored. The erro portion contains only one such instance.

The following are the environment details:
Ubuntu 22.04
CUDA 10.1
GCC version 8
Python 3.7 with Anaconda
torch==1.1.0
torchvision==0.3.0

The requirements are as of the requirement file in the repository.

I did the following things:

- Reinstall and upgrade setuptools
- Manually install the github repository through `pip` and `--use-pep517` flag

None of the above has worked.

Answer (score 0):

most solutions I have seen so far seem to revolve around downgrading to a previous version : setuptools==58.2.0

It worked for me so far..

I would be glad to know if you found something better.

See also : [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219375/setuptoolsdeprecationwarning-setup-py-install-is-deprecated-use-build-and-pip)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35054180)